# Stay on current page after submit button in YII Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to submit a form , after form submition the current page should stay on with user entered datas . how to achieve this ?

```
public function actionUpload()
    {

       $model=new UploadModel();
       $basemodel=new BaseContactList();
       $importmodel=new ImportedFilesModel(); 


        $importmodel->name =$basemodel->name;  
        $importmodel->import_date = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $importmodel->server_path = $temp;
        $importmodel->file_name = $name;
        $importmodel->crm_base_contact_id = $crm_base_contact_id;

        if ($importmodel->save())
            echo "Import saved";
        else 
            echo "Import Not Saved";
        unset($_POST['BaseContactList']);    
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);

    }
```

This line `"$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);"` goes to previous page but the user entered values are cleared . How to redirect to previous page without clearing the values in the form ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same with when you view the error message after failed model saving. Instead of doing redirection, you can just pass the saved model to the form.

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $model = new Model();
    if (isset($_POST[get_class($model)]){
       $model->setAttributes($_POST[get_class($model)]);
       if ($model->save()){
          //do nothing
          //usually people do a redirection here `$this->redirect('index');`
          //or you can save a flash message
          Yii::app()->user->setFlash('message', 'Successfully save form');
       } else {
          Yii::app()->user->setFlash('message', 'Failed to save form');
       }
    }
    //this will pass the model posted by the form to the view,
    //regardless whether the save is successful or not.
    $this->render('index', array('model' => $model));
}
```

In the `index` view you can do something like.

```
<?php if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('message')):?>
    <div class="message"><?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('message');?></div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm();?>
    <!-- show the form with $model here --->
<?php echo CHtml::endForm();?>
```

The downside is, when you accidentally hit Refresh button (F5), it will try to post the form again.

Or you can save it using user session using `setFlash`.

```
public function actionUpload()
{

   $model=new UploadModel();
   $basemodel=new BaseContactList();
   $importmodel=new ImportedFilesModel(); 


    $importmodel->name =$basemodel->name;  
    $importmodel->import_date = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $importmodel->server_path = $temp;
    $importmodel->file_name = $name;
    $importmodel->crm_base_contact_id = $crm_base_contact_id;

    if ($importmodel->save())
        echo "Import saved";
    else 
        echo "Import Not Saved";
    unset($_POST['BaseContactList']);    

    //here we go
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('form', serialize($basemodel)); 
    //
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);

}
```

In the previous form, you load the value from the session.

```
public function actionForm(){
    if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('form')){
       $basemodel = unserialize(Yii::app()->user->getFlash('form');
    } else {
       $basemodel = new BaseContactList();
    }
    $this->render('form', array('basemodel' => $basemodel));
}
```

Comment: Please see the edited post with code, i want to redirect to previous page without clearing the values.

Comment: The value won't be cleared because you passed the same value post by previous form.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether really such a long code is needed to do such a thing but I can simply do it by this.
Suppose i have an **actionUpdate**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {   


        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['Products']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Products'];
                        $model->save();
                   // remove this redirect() line
        // $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->productId));       
            }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

If in your action, **you are redirecting after saving your data** then **just remove that line** and you are done, **provided that you are rendering the form again in the following lines**
If you are not rendering the form in the next lines then you can do it yourself like

```
if($model->save())
{
$this->render('update',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: this would exactly do what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
if ($importmodel->save())
  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Redirect to the same action and send the model loaded as an arguement

Comment: would be helpfull to say where you can do it if you could give me your controller code

Comment: Code Pasted Please see